# Jenkins git fetch timeout

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-2

I am running Jenkins 2.0 on my Mac OS X Mavericks machine at work. I'm trying to pull down a repository from an internal server. However, the job hangs on  the `git fetch` call for 10 minutes and then times out.

If I manually run `git clone` or `git fetch` from a shell script (from within Jenkins), I get the same overall result, except the job hangs endlessly.

I can run a `clone` or `fetch` command from the Terminal just fine.

I'm wondering if this is some sort of user permission error that needs to be resolved.

Here is the log:

```
Started by user Colin Basnett
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Service
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username jenkins # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/git8010092725741498465.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:766)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1022)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git/'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:764)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: According to the log, the git command sets the option `core.askpass=true`. Thus git is waiting for a password which is never given.

Comment: I saw there is an error in the log "fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://192.168.4.40/Bonobo.Git.Server/Service.git/'", maybe need to check the Jenkins git configuration first. For me the path to set Jenkins git configurations: `Manage Jenkins` - `Configurate System` - `Gitlab`(Since we're using gitlab server) - `Credentials`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For me it was short timeout. In your case you may want to do the following:

1. Increase timeout for cloning and checkout

   1. Go to job configuration and find git section
   2. Add -> Advanced clone behaviours. There you can specify timeout and check 'shallow copy' (which is faster)
   3. Add -> Advanced checkout behaviours. You can set time out for checkout.
2. Make sure you provided right credentials in Job configuration - Source Code Management - Git - Credentials

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was agonizing with this trouble for 2 days.
I use Bitbucket folder, pipelines and autobuiding PRs. Your advice helped me to remove this issue: `ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'`

Comment: Default timeout value (10 minutes) is a bit confusing (I'd expect something like ten _seconds_). Anyway, shallow mode really helps when GitHub connection is unstable.

Comment: Didn't know about the shallow copy as well. This makes the checkout process significantly faster.